# How can make/embed my own product display design in wooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a wordpress website in which I am using wooCommerce plugin for products. My problem is that I want to make my own product display block design using woocommerce how can I make my own design for products display and replace the default.

I have searched a lot to solve the problem but cannot solve it please help me in this issue.

[image]

Comment: Add some code of what ever you have tried.

Comment: In short, you use template overrides. https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Thanks sir for your ans after making the changes i will get back to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to woocommerce plugin folder. Inside that find a folder 'templates'. Copy this folder to your theme folder and rename the folder 'woocommerce'.

Now every template is there, you can modify those files as per your requirement.

From your provided screenshot, I can suggest you to edit the page called 'content-product.php', this page gives you output of product blocks.

And the listing page is 'archive-product.php'.